# Recover unknown vector through shifted argmax queries

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity, sorting

I am interested in finding an efficient algorithm for the following problem:

Let $x \in [0,1]^n$ be some vector, with $x_n = 1$.
We want to recover $x$, solely by asking queries of the form $\texttt{argmax}(x + v)$ where $v \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is an arbitrary additive shift.

A simple algorithm is to do binary search over each component of $x$ one-by-one.
This requires $O(n \log 1/\epsilon)$ queries to recover $x$ up to precision $\epsilon$.

A more involved approach is to first sort $x$ (which can be done with $n$ queries) and then perform $n$ binary searches to find the gaps between adjacent elements. I believe this should give something like $O(n \log 1/(n\epsilon))$.

Is it possible to do better? My intuition is that it might be, as every query $i \gets \texttt{argmax}(x + v)$ gives us $\log_2 n$ bits of information.
So in principle we could hope for an algorithm that uses $O(\frac{n \log 1/\epsilon}{\log_2 n})$ queries.

Comment: One strategy that comes to mind: At each step, let $\mathcal{S}$ denote the set of all $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ that are consistent with the responses to prior queries ($\mathcal{S}$ is the feasible region of a system of difference equations); sample $s$ randomly from $\mathcal{S}$; and let $v=-s$ and make a query with $v$.  Heuristically, I suspect that the response to this query might be approximately uniformly distributed on $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$, hence convey $\lg n$ bits of information at each step.  I have no bound or proof for worst-case number of queries.

Comment: Cross-posted https://mathoverflow.net/questions/458321/recover-unknown-vector-through-shifted-argmax-queries